# How to Run cucumber Feature files in parallel

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I want to run Features files (not scenario) to run in Parallel.

First Feature:

```
Feature: Refund item for Jeff

  Scenario: 01 Collect Details
    Given Collect Jeff details
    And Collect receipts for purchase
  
  Scenario: 02 Refund
    When Jeff returns the microwave
    Then Jeff should be refunded $100
```

Second Feature:

```
Feature: Refund item for Dave

  Scenario: 01 Collect Details
    Given Collect Dave details
    And Collect receipts for purchase
  
  Scenario: 02 Refund
    When Dave returns the microwave
    Then Dave should be refunded $100
```

I am using Cucumber-java with testng. I am able to run the scenarios in parallel. But I really want to run the Features in Parallel.
I already implemented below code for parallel scenario.

```
public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achive that with `TestNg`. **But.** You can achieve that with `JUnit4`. Basically That is how parallelisation works for `JUnit 4` according to [Cucumber specification](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java).

> Cucumber can be executed in parallel using JUnit and Maven test execution plugins. **In JUnit the feature files are run in parallel rather than scenarios, which means all the scenarios in a feature file will be executed by the same thread.** You can use either Maven Surefire or Failsafe plugin to execute the runners.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Scenarios are intended to be executed independently from each other. Depending on what you are testing, you could turn all scenarios in a feature file into a single scenario.

However you should consider rewriting your scenarios such that they do not depend on the actions in previous scenarios.

Typically this means writing scenarios like:

```
Scenario: Do a thing
  Given a thing
  When a thing is used
  Then something happens

Scenario: Do another thing next
  Given a thing that was used
  When a thing is used again
  Then something else happens
```

To implement `a thing that was used` you can reuse the methods you've already written to implement the steps of the first scenario.